# How to add a table reference to an entry in another table in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have to create a website where users can log in and create and share music playlists. I'm using Asp.net MVC with C# in Visual Studio.

Each playlist is an entry in the playlists table and has the fields PlaylistName, UserId (id of the user the playlist belongs to), and list of tracks in the playlist in either the form of a vector (the vector contains IDs to tracks contained the tracks table) or in the form of a reference to a table that contains the tracks associated with this playlist (so each playlist entry in the playlists table has its own table). Being new to ASP.NET and databases in general I'm not really sure if either of these approaches are ideal and even how to implement them. If I went with the vector method could I do this:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Playlist
    {
        public string PlaylistName { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public List<int> Tracks { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlaylistDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then scaffold the model?

For the other method I'm not sure how to use visual studio to set that up.

Answer (score 2):

So if im reading this right you have a playlist that has a bunch of tracks?
Add an ID to playlist, something like an int will do

```
public class Playlist
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string PlaylistName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<int> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

I have no clue what your track object looks like, so lets pretend it has a name and an ID.
I am assuming each track only belongs to one playlist only.
If so, add a "playlistID" to each track.

```
public class Track
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public int PlayListID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now this links the track to a playlist.
If you're using entity framework as your data access and it kinda looks like you are, you can add virtual properties and entity framework understands the relations to get you what you want.

So you can go add "tracks" to the playlist class like this :

```
 public class Playlist
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string PlaylistName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Track> Tracks{ get; set; }
}
```

and whenever you use the tracks property it will go and find the child records.
similarly on the track child record you can add the following "Playlist" property and it will find the parent whenever needed.

```
public class Track
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public int PlayListID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual Playlist Playlist {get;set;}
}
```

if you're using entity framework 6 with codefirst migrations this should just work.

EDIT ::

if you need a many to many relationship then you simply update the tracks as follows :

```
public class Track
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Playlist> Playlists {get;set;}
}
```

i removed the playlist ID on the track and also the virtual property is now a collection of playlists. entity framework should automatically create the reference table "Track_Playlists" or whatever in between.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, total newbie here. I should have pointed out each track can appear in more than one playlist.